# FreeBSD 8 and Samba 3.3 smb_panic

Tags: samba, freebsd

What is causing samba to crash? Need help diagnosing ...

```
[2010/06/14 16:11:42,  0] lib/fault.c:fault_report(40)
  ===============================================================
[2010/06/14 16:11:42,  0] lib/fault.c:fault_report(41)
  INTERNAL ERROR: Signal 11 in pid 951 (3.3.8)
  Please read the Trouble-Shooting section of the Samba3-HOWTO
[2010/06/14 16:11:42,  0] lib/fault.c:fault_report(43)

  From: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba3-HOWTO.pdf
[2010/06/14 16:11:42,  0] lib/fault.c:fault_report(44)
  ===============================================================
[2010/06/14 16:11:42,  0] lib/util.c:smb_panic(1673)
  PANIC (pid 951): internal error
[2010/06/14 16:53:40,  0] smbd/server.c:main(1274)
```

Edit:

A bit more info --

log.smbd:

```
[2010/06/14 15:59:02,  0] smbd/server.c:main(1274)
smbd version 3.3.8 started.
      Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2009
[2010/06/14 15:59:02,  0] printing/print_cups.c:cups_connect(103)
Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
[2010/06/14 15:59:02,  0] printing/print_cups.c:cups_connect(103)
Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
```

smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = WASH
netbios name = PROD1

[media]
path = /jon/media
read only = no
guest ok = yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rc.conf file looks good, though you might want to just simplify to `samba_enable="YES"`

Having a pid file in `/var/run` doesn't mean anything necessarily. It could be an old file, or any one of a hundred other things; it's not procfs.

Check the /var/log/samba directory for log files; there should be several in there, the one with the most recent time stamp should contain helpful information (like a crash reason).

**Edit:**
This may be a known problem with 3.3.x on FreeBSD 7/8/9 with Service Discovery turned on. This is turned on by default for some reason. To fix:

```
cd /usr/ports/net/samba33
make config
uncheck "With DNS service discovery support" (if it wasn't checked, this isn't the problem)
make clean; make && make deinstall && make reinstall
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/samba restart
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I updated my question with what I can see in the smbd.log (the other logs of the related daemons look clean) and the smb.conf. Anything look strange?

Comment: Nothing abnormal. Try stopping the daemon via the rc.d script; then start `smbd -F -d -s /usr/local/etc/smb.conf`. Then switch to another console and run `smbclient -L prod1`; check back on the first console and see if there's any interesting error messages.

Comment: Same thing, but I did just find this in the log where it looks like it's crashing, I think this may be the root issue? smbclient -L prod1


[2010/06/14 16:11:42,  0] lib/fault.c:fault_report(40)
  ===============================================================
[2010/06/14 16:11:42,  0] lib/fault.c:fault_report(41)
  INTERNAL ERROR: Signal 11 in pid 951 (3.3.8)
[2010/06/14 16:11:42,  0] lib/util.c:smb_panic(1673)
  PANIC (pid 951): internal error
[2010/06/14 16:53:40,  0] smbd/server.c:main(1274)

Comment: Yeah, Sig 11 is a Segmentation Fault (invalid memory reference). Did you compile from the ports tree, or install from a package?

Comment: From ports ( /usr/ports/net/samba33 )

Comment: That was it, thanks so much.

# smbclient -L prod1
Enter root's password: